# What is the 'TE correlation' in the CMB, or 'temperature-E-mode' correlation, aka 'temperature-polarization' correlation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

There are several places on the web that mention this, a couple in some technical detail, but I cannot wrap my head around what exactly it means...